# How to directly handle M:M relationships using DataGrids and Entity Framework

Tags: c#, wpf, entity-framework, wpfdatagrid

Using a Database First approach with EF6, I currently have 2 entities in a M:N relationship (Users and Roles) that I would like to be able to set up in one WPF page. My goal is to have 2 data grids in a master-detail relationship that support in-line editing - the top will show all users and the bottom will show the selected user's roles. I have successfully implemented the users data grid with in-line editing, but, when editing records on the second data grid, it directly alters the Roles table, instead of the relationship.

Window XAML:

```
                    <DataGrid Name="DataGridUsers"  AutoGenerateColumns="False"  IsTextSearchEnabled="True" SelectionChanged="DataGridUsers_SelectionChanged" Margin="15" MaxHeight="300" CellEditEnding="DataGridUsers_CellEditEnding">
                        <DataGrid.Columns>
                            <DataGridTextColumn Binding="{Binding Username, Mode=TwoWay}" Header="Username"/>
                            <DataGridTextColumn Binding="{Binding FirstName, Mode=TwoWay}" Header="First Name" />
                            <DataGridTextColumn Binding="{Binding LastName, Mode=TwoWay}" Header="Last Name"/>
                            <DataGridTextColumn Binding="{Binding email, Mode=TwoWay}" Header="Email"/>
                        </DataGrid.Columns>
                    </DataGrid>


                <DataGrid Name="DataGridUserRoles"  AutoGenerateColumns="False" Margin="15" CellEditEnding="DataGridUserRoles_CellEditEnding" >
                    <DataGrid.Columns>
                        <DataGridTextColumn Binding="{Binding RoleName, Mode=TwoWay}" Header="Role Name" />
                    </DataGrid.Columns>
                </DataGrid>
```

I use the following 2 lines to set the ItemsSource for the Users Datagrid on Window Load:

```
context.Users.Include(a => a.Roles).Load();
DataGridUsers.ItemsSource = context.Users.Local;
```

When the selection changes on the Users Datagrid, I use the following to set the Roles Data Grid ItemsSource.

```
var CurrentUser = DataGridUsers.SelectedItem as User;
DataGridUserRoles.ItemsSource = context.Roles.Local.Where(x => x.Users.Any(y => y.UserID == CurrentUser.UserID)).ToList();
```

This correctly populates the values into the Roles datagrid based on entries in the UsersRoles table.

All of my saving is handled by a generic save button on the form which saves the entire context asynchronously.

```
    private async void SaveAll()
    {
        await (context.SaveChangesAsync());
    }
```

When I edit the Roles Data grid, I am directly manipulating data in my Roles table and not in the UsersRoles junction table. My goal is for the bottom table to directly update the UsersRoles table so that User permissions can be managed through the application. How do I adjust the binding for the Roles datagrid to achieve this?

Comment: If I understand correctly, the user will manipulate the role name and you expect that a different role item with appropriate name will be assigned to the user based on this input?

Comment: The intention would be that the user would used the second grid view to add or remove roles that are associated to that user. The actual management of what roles exist would be performed in a separate component. For example, permissions A, B and C already Exist. User Foo has permission A assigned to them only. When I select Foo, A should show in the list, and I have the ability to add B or C, and remove A if desired.

Comment: Well, a `DataGridTextColumn` and a `Binding RoleName` looks a lot like the user will just input text. You can try using a `DataGridComboBoxColumn` with `ItemsSource="{Binding ListOfAllRoles}"` and `SelectedValue="{Binding SelectedRole}"` then on saving, change the assigned user roles to contain the `SelectedRole` of all detail rows. Sorry, don't have time to write a propera answer with example right now.